# Can I get a textfield in Monotouch to appear as a lined notepad - the same appearance as the 'Notes' application

Tags: xamarin.ios, textfield

I am experimenting with monotouch for the first time. I have essentially finished my first application, however, I am re-visiting the application to make it more appealing visually and was wondering if I could make a textfield look like the 'Notes' application?

Thanks in advance to those who can help.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easy and simple way is to to do something like the Notes App.

Is to use an UITextView and set an Backgroundimage/BackgroundColor, which looks like a paper.